# Spring MVC, force JSON response in plain request

Tags: json, forms, spring

I am using Spring 3.0.6 and i have a single controller for uploading files to the server. I am using a script to upload using XmlHttpRequest for browsers that support it while the rest of the browsers submit a (hidden) multipart form. The problem however is that when a form is submitted it sends the following header:

```
Accept  text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
```

I figure that due to this header the Controller which is marked with `@ResponseBody` replies with the response been converted to XML instead of JSON. Is there a way to get around this without hacking the form submit request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force JSON using `@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")`. I don't remember if this is available in 3.0 but it is available in 3.1 and 3.2 for sure.

As others noted, Jackson needs to be on your classpath.

Comment: This looks good, however as you said i don't know if it's applicable to Spring 3.0

Comment: in addtion to this you need that the reqeust will have Accept header , like this   Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8" , so spring mvc will know which convertor to use to build the correct response .

Answer (score 2):

Thank you!  I was having exactly the same issue and your post resolved my problem.

On the UI I'm using JQuery with this file upload plugin: 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Here's my completed method (minus the biz logic):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void  handleUpload( @RequestParam("fileToUpload") CommonsMultipartFile uploadFile, ServletResponse response){

    List<UploadStatus> status = new ArrayList<UploadStatus>();
    UploadStatus uploadStatus = new UploadStatus();
    status.add(uploadStatus); 

    if(uploadFile == null || StringUtils.isBlank(uploadFile.getOriginalFilename())){
        uploadStatus.setMessage(new Message(MessageType.important, "File name must be specified."));
    }else{
        uploadStatus.setName(uploadFile.getOriginalFilename());
        uploadStatus.setSize(uploadFile.getSize());
    }
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    try {
        JsonGenerator generator = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(response.getOutputStream(), JsonEncoding.UTF8); 
        mapper.writeValue(generator, status); 
        generator.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a JSON response, you can easily accomplish that by having the [Jackson JARs](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) on your classpath.  Spring will auto-magically pick up on them being there and will convert your `@ResponseBody` to JSON.

Comment: But i do, i am using Jackson. The same method when it replies to a request with accept:application/json header sends it as JSON. But it seems that Spring MVC replies with XML when it is absent

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by getting rid off `@ResponseBody` and instead doing manually the conversion (always using Jackson), i.e.

```
Response r = new Response();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonGenerator generator = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(response.getOutputStream(), JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    try {
        File f = uploadService.getAjaxUploadedFile(request);
        r.setData(f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        r = new Response(new ResponseError(e.getMessage(), ""));
    }
    mapper.writeValue(generator, r);
    generator.flush();
```

Does anyone know another way? I tried setting up a [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations) but i don't want to break any other controllers by assigning all hmtl to json. Also, i tried to do it for this method only via a custom viewresolver but when i setup a jsonview and use `BeanNameViewResolver` although the response is correctly converted to JSON the server throws an
`HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:` exception, with Request method 'POST' not supported and set status to 404.